# how to tell if I need a better server or separate DB from web tier?

Tags: apache-2.2, mysql, php

I have a typical media temple DV Rage server, boxed both apache and mysql.

But what if i use 2 DV Base separating DB and apache? Will there be any performance gain? What is the rule here?

I should upgrade to DV Extreme later or buy one more DV Base to host DB?

Answer (score 1):

"it depends". Is anything on your current server maxed out? Memory? CPU? I/O? Diskspace? If you answer "yes": is the maxed out resource required by both components (web tier and db)? If it is you might gain, depending on the network connection (latency, throughput) of the connection between the two machines.

If apache maxes out CPU and db maxes out memory you might not gain much by separating the two.

These are just examples - to really answer your question one needs to take a lot more aspects into account than you name.